# El carrusel de Bootstrap aparece demasiado pequeño en pantallas formato móvil

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

He agregado un carrusel con 3 imágenes a mi web. Si bien en pantallas de ordenador se muestra correctamente, en dispositivos con pantallas de menor tamaño el carrusel aparece demasiado pequeño, en disonancia con el resto de la web. Además, por alguna razón que desconozco, la barra de navegación superior queda parcialmente superpuesta al carrusel. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Mi objetivo es que el carrusel tenga el tamaño que ya tiene en su versión "desktop", pero que en la versión móvil tenga un tamaño superior al de las imágenes que se encuentran más abajo en la web.

Os dejo abajo el código HTML y CSS, además de un par de capturas mostrando la diferencia:

```css
.brand-logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 6px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#navbar {
  font-family: "Delius";
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #504658;
}

.title-navbar {
  font-family: "Delius Swash Caps";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

img {

  border-radius: 10%;
}

#highlights {
  background-color: #ce2e6c;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Delius Swash Caps";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3.3rem;
  color: #f0decb;
}

.highlights-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 46px;
}

#carousel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6% auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.highlights-image {
  width: 60%;
}

.highlights-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12%;
}

.collection-col {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#collection {
  background-color: #ffb5b5;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.collection-image {
  width: 60%;
}

.see-more {
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  border: 2px;
  font-family: 'Delius';
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
  <section id="navbar">
    <nav id="navbar-bar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand title-navbar" href="#">
        <img class="brand brand-logo" src="images/brand.jpg" width="35" height="35" alt="Brand" class="d-inline-block align-top">
        Uwe Drawings
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#highlights">Highlights</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#bio">Bio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#collection">Collection</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <!-- Hightlights -->
  <section id="highlights">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide container-fluid" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators highlights-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="highlights-image" src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="highlights-image" src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="highlights-image" src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-button1" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-button2" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <!-- Bio -->
  <section id="bio">

  </section>

  <!-- Collection -->
  <section id="collection">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/8.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/7.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/11.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/12.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
        <img class="collection-image" src="images/10.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="see-more btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #504658" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collection-2">See More</button>
    <div id="collection-2" class="collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/9.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/6.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
          <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, no hace falta que coloques el código en otras paginas, lo puedes pegar directamente en la pagina.

Comment: Tienes dos problemas a considerar en tu CSS. 1ro estás asignando un `width: 60%` a **TODAS** las imágenes, y 2do estás asignando un `width: 50%` al carrusel. Esto hace, por ej, que en pantallas más pequeñas, las imágenes se reduzcan a la mitad del ancho del dispositivo. Corrige lo que te comento, puedes usar valores automáticos o usar media queries (aunque si usas Bootstrap, esto debiste tomarlo en cuenta antes)

Comment: @JheymanMejia Sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Lo que quiero conseguir es que en ordenador se vea exactamente igual (un 50% de la pantalla) pero que en móviles se vea a un tamaño similar o mayor al de las imágenes que hay más abajo (las cuales están organizadas con el grid de Bootstrap).

Comment: Diego, sigue las recomendaciones de @erika_chan y coloca el código aquí en la página (es más importante el código que las imágenes). Así tendrás más posibilidades de que tu pregunta sea respondida.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar el siguiente código

CSS

```
<style>

    .brand-logo {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 6px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #navbar {
        font-family: "Delius";
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .navbar {
        background-color: #504658;
    }

    .title-navbar {
        font-family: "Delius Swash Caps";
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
    }

    img {

        border-radius: 10%;
    }

    #highlights {
        background-color: #ce2e6c;
        padding: 1%;
        margin-top: 4%;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Delius Swash Caps";
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 3.3rem;
        color: #f0decb;
    }

    .highlights-title {
        position: relative;
        top: 46px;
    }

    #carousel {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 6% auto;
        position: relative;
        /*width: 50%;*/
    }

    .highlights-image {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .highlights-indicators {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -12%;
    }

    .collection-col {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #collection {
        background-color: #ffb5b5;
        padding-right: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .collection-image {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .see-more {
        margin-top: 45px;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        border: 2px;
        font-family: 'Delius';
        color: white;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
</style>
```

HTML





Uwe Drawings







Highlights


Bio


Collection


Pricing


Get In Touch

```
<!-- Hightlights -->
<section id="highlights">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-7 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-12 ">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators highlights-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="highlights-image img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="highlights-image img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="highlights-image img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-button1" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-button2" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Bio -->
<section id="bio">

</section>

<!-- Collection -->
<section id="collection">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=8.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=7.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=11.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=12.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
            <img class="collection-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=10.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="see-more btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #504658" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collection-2">See More</button>
    <div id="collection-2" class="collapse">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/9.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/6.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 collection-col">
                <img class="collection-image" src="images/brand.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

[codeply run](https://www.codeply.com/p/ycLogtH081)

**Explicación**

Hice varios cambios, pero es solo ordenar el codigo.

- En el CSS, eliminé el width en #carousel, porque eso lo manejo desde el tag COL en el div.
- cambié el width en css .highlights-image a 80% porque aun en resoluciones bajas no hay forma de ampliarlo si tienes un 60% del ancho disponible (seguía quedando pequeño)
- en el html, agregué un div que envuelve al carousel (). Esto sirve para regular anchos variables aplicando breakpoint por resolucion. Puedes jugar con los numeros 6, 7 etc para encontrar una mejor reoslucion que te guste.
- en el html agregue el d-flex justify-content-center al carousel para que quede centrado.

Buena suerte!